# ConstrainLayout not respecting the hierarchy

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

[image: Screen Shot]I have this layout

```
....................
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_remember_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textinput2"
        android:text="@string/keep_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textinput2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_signin_login" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signin_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cb_remember_login"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="75dp"
        android:text="@string/signin"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="30sp" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cb_remember_login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_forgot_login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    <include
        layout="@layout/view_circle_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_signin_login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="btn_signin_login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_signin_login"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/btn_signin_login" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin_login"
        android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_signin_login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_copyrights_login"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

...........][1]][1]
```

Here is `view_circle_progress.xml`

```
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:indeterminateTint="@color/red">

</ProgressBar>
```

You can see my included layout comes after the button but in the picture you can see it's actually beneath the button. Please help with a solution. Also except the included layout all the views are in a chain.

Comment: `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_forgot_login"` and `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tv_forgot_login" ` should be topToTopOf the button instead.

Comment: @Ibrahim not working

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: edited my question now check please

Comment: What do you want to see? The include on top of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Android 5.0 elevation is introduced. A button has a default elevation that's why it was always showing on top. Setting elevation value to my include layout solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `xml`, click design. The on the upper left, corner you will see an icon similar to a blueprint. Click on it and you will get your layout as a blue print. Then click on the element that you want, you will see four points on all sides. Click on the upper point and drag it to the upper `bar`(`menu`, etc.). That way you will attach it and it will stay in place. If you want to make offset look on you right above the properties you will see a box representing the item with its constraints, just put the distance you want, and you will have your offset.